# Gobble the next char if it is whitespace or tilde

Tags: macros, expl3, white-space, parsing

I want this macro to gobble the next character in the input stream only if it is whitespace (according to the char code) *or* it's the tilde character (i.e., a non-breaking space).

My current attempt to do this is the following, where `\~` is just a placeholder for the literal tilde character, since I know this isn't a proper escape sequence or macro.

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \gobblespace { } {
    \peek_catcode_remove:NTF ~ {} {
        \peek_charcode:NTF \~ {} {}
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

Seems that I might need the macro to be expandable, given the usage context (postnotes in biblatex citations).

Here's a bit of context, as requested in the comments.

I am defining commands to use in citation postnotes (biblatex), similar in behaviour to `\pno` and `\ppno`.

```latex
% Define commands for citing chapter and section numbers.
\NewDocumentCommand \sno { } { \bibstring{section} }
\NewDocumentCommand \snos { } { \bibstring{sections} }
\NewDocumentCommand \chno { } { \bibstring{chapter} }
\NewDocumentCommand \chnos { } { \bibstring{chapters} }
```

However, I want to allow the bibliography strings to be customisable, such as:

```latex
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    section = {\S\gobblespace}, % *should not* be followed by space when printed
    sections = {\S\S\gobblespace}, % *should not* be followed by space when printed
    chapter = {ch.},
    chapters = {chs.},
}
```

but also like:

```latex
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    section = {sec.}, % *should* be followed by space when printed
    sections = {secs.}, % *should* be followed by space when printed
    chapter = {ch.},
    chapters = {chs.},
}
```

Comment: Does `\gobblespace` need to be expandable?

Comment: Lookahead is generally not (reliably) doable expandably (that's why you can't have `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \foo { o } {#1}`, for example).  If you just want to remove trailing spaces while typesetting, you don't need expandability.  If you _do_ need, then a concrete use-case could help finding a solution

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ah right. I've updated my post with my concrete use-case now.

Comment: Given your use case, how about `\def\gobblespace#1{#1}`? (note: I am not a `biblatex` user, but I have done such things in bibtex, with success)

Comment: @Noldorin My knowledge of BibLaTeX is close to nonexistent, but it looks to me that you don't need expandability (thus Steven's answer should work).

Comment: This all feels like you are trying to re-implement the punctuation tracker in `biblatex`: have you tried solving from that end?

Comment: @JosephWright How do you mean? This is more about spaces (including non-breaking), and i don't see any existing functionality for that.

Comment: @Noldorin As in, as you are inserting a string, shouldn't it be something like `\space\bibstring{section}\addspace`?

Comment: @JosephWright I don't know, but the standard way to (literally) write page numbers in citation postnotes is e.g. `\pno~123`, so I wanted something similar for section numbers e.g. `\sno~9`, which will expand to `sec.~9` or `§9` depending on how the bibliography string is defined.

Comment: @Noldorin I think you have an XY question here.  Your problem (probably: it's been a while since I last dug through BibLaTeX) can't really be solved with peeking ahead because BibLaTeX writes the bibliography step by step, rather than leaving the whole thing in the input stream in one go, so what you end up is (very, very) roughly `\S\gobblespace\some@internal@that@continues@printing@the@bibliography`, so your `\gobblespace` macro never sees any space (to check that, just try defining `\def\gobblespace{\show}` and see what shows up).  I think you need a solution from the BibLaTeX side...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ah, the `\show` is revealing the next input token is `\blx@endunit`...

Comment: @Noldorin Exactly, that's deep inside BibLaTeX's output routine.  You need a BibLaTeX-specific solution here.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yeah, I'm going to close this and ask a new more concrete question. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-expandable token cycle that can do this.  In the MWE, I make `Q` active and let it to `\gobblespace`, so that it is easy to introduce spaces after the macro call.  Otherwise you would need something like `\expandafter\gobblespace\space`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\abortgobble{\tcpush{\empty\endgobblespace}}
\tokcycleenvironment\gobblespace
{\tcpush{\empty##1}\abortgobble}
{\tcpushgroup{\empty##1}\abortgobble}
{\tctestifcon{\if\detokenize{~}\detokenize{##1}}
  {}{\tcpush{\empty##1}}\abortgobble}
{\ifimplicittok\tcpush{\empty##1}\fi\abortgobble}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\Q=\active
\letQ\gobblespace
xQx

xQ x

xQ\today

xQ{\itshape x}x

xQ~x

\makeatletter
xQ\@sptoken x % <-IMPLICIT SPACE EXCLUDED FROM GOBBLE

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the MWE, implicit spaces are not absorbed, since normal argument absorption would, likewise, not skip past implicit spaces.  However, if you want implicit spaces gobbled, the above code can easily adjusted to leave out the implicit space check.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I may have been wrong about it not needing to be expandable though... I thought it didn't, but perhaps because I'm using it within a citation (biblatex) postnote...

Comment: @Noldorin Yes, I am not surprised that you might need it expandable.  `tokcycle` will be of no help there, but let us hope another expandable approach arises in another answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Indeed, and thank you. Interesting to learn about tokcycle and its approach in any case.

Comment: @Noldorin Now that you have provided some use cases in your Question, I would note that you may need `\noexpand` before `\gobblespace`, if you are trying to use my tokcycle approach.  But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's why it was causing errors. I'll try, thanks.

Comment: I'm still getting the following error:
```
./foo.tex:262: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.262 
      
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 262.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> foo.tex
             
! Emergency stop.
<*> foo.tex
```

Comment: @Noldorin Well, it was a thought...however, I am not a biblatexer, so I am of limited use in further diagnosis.

Comment: Yep, It's a decent idea, and may apply regardless... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `\S` is *always* followed by some token that's not a brace (either open or closed), you can do

```
\newcommand{\gobblespace}[1]{\ifx#1~\else\expandafter#1\fi}
```

because this will automatically gobble spaces when looking for the argument. This will also reinsert the found token if not `~`.

I'm not sure where the need of expandability arises, though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\gobblespaceortilde}{}
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:NV \peek_charcode_remove_ignore_spaces:NT \c_tilde_str {}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\addsectionsymbol}{\S\gobblespaceortilde}

\begin{document}

\addsectionsymbol~X

\expandafter\addsectionsymbol\space X

\addsectionsymbol X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that your second (expl3) macro does indeed work, although only if it is included at the end of e.g. `\sno`, that is, `\NewDocumentCommand \sno { } { \bibstring{section} \gobblespaceortilde }`. If it is included instead at the end of the bibliography string definition, e.g. `section = {\S\gobblespaceottilde}` or `section = {\S\noexpand\gobblespaceottilde}`, it does nothing (although no errors).

Comment: @Noldorin Lack of examples…

Comment: A simple example is `\autocite[\sno~3]{citekey}`, which is capable of gobbling the tilde if `\gobblespaceottilde` is appended to the body of `\sno`, but not if it is appended to the definition of the bibliographic string `section`, per above.